# dovecot-sieve filter Как получить body письма или его исходный текст

Tags: postfix, dovecot

Есть почтовый сервер postfix+dovecot

Цель: Когда на ящик user@example.com приходит письмо мне нужно запустить bash скрипт передав в него данные из письма

Пытаюсь написать dovecot sieve filter

```
require "envelope";
require "variables";
require "vnd.dovecot.pipe";

if envelope :matches "From" "*" { set "sender" "${0}"; }
if header :matches "Date" "*" { set "date" "${0}"; }
if header :matches "Content-Type" "*" { set "content_type" "${0}"; }
if header :matches "subject" "*" { set "subject" "${0}"; }
if header :matches "message-id" "*" { set "message_id" "${0}"; }

if envelope :matches "To" "user@example.com" {
   set "recipient" "${0}";

   pipe "forwarding_cimp.sh" ["message_id:${message_id} date:${date} content_type:${content_type} sender:${sender} recipient:${recipient} subject:${subject}"];
}
```

но я не могу найти информацию о том как мне передать тело письма, с учетом того, что в письме может быть вложения и т.д.

Подскажите как в переменную записать body, attachments и т.д.
Самым идеальным вариантом было бы получение исходного raw_text письма

Comment: https://github.com/tonioo/sievelib - видели такое? Там вроде как заявлена работа с Body сообщения.